# NextJs: Static export with dynamic routing

Tags: azure, next.js

I am deploying my Next.js app on Azure and it will throw a 404 on page refresh if I navigate to the module pages e.g `www.site.com/overview`.

I have followed the guide for deploying on azure here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-nextjs.

However it has some conflicting advice, it says to export it using `next build && next export` and to also dynamically map the routes to avoid the 404 error, however when I do that Next.js throws an error:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/modules/emergency-closing". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
Error:
Error: you provided query values for /modules/emergency-closing which is an auto-exported page. These can not be applied since the page can no longer be re-rendered on the server. To disable auto-export for this page add `getInitialProps`
```

What is the correct way to export the app and run it on Azure?

**next.config.js**

```js
    const modules = require('./data/modules')

    module.exports = {
      trailingSlash: true,
      async exportPathMap() {
        const paths = {
          '/': { page: '/' },
        }
        //
        Object.keys(modules).map((module) => {
          paths[`/modules/${modules[module].slug}`] = {
            page: '/modules/[moduleSlug]',
            query: { moduleSlug: modules[module].slug },
          }
        })
    
        return paths
      },
    }
```

**modules.js**

```js
    module.exports = {
      overview: {
        id: 6,
        name: 'overview',
        slug: 'overview',
      },
      'special-features': {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Special features',
        slug: 'special-features',
      },
      diagnosis: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Diagnosis',
        slug: 'diagnosis',
      },
      'emergency-closing': {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Emergency closing',
        slug: 'emergency-closing',
      },
      'side-window-settings': {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Side window settings',
        slug: 'side-window-settings',
      },
    }
```

**package.json**

```json
      "build": "next build && next export",
```